# Building Sencha Touch app with Cordova - [You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project] error

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I am trying to build a sencha touch 2.4 application for Android using the sencha cmd "sencha app build native" and I am getting an error that I can't solve.

"You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project"

I am working on Win7, using sencha touch 2.4 and sencha cmd v5.1. I downloaded the Android sdk (API 19) using the Android SDK Manager.

This is the command output:

```
D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA>sencha app build native
Sencha Cmd v5.1.1.39
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : native
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Concatenating output to file D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA/build/temp/production/GeoMapTematicPA/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
[INF] writing content to D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending content to  D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA/bootstrap.json
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (me.callParent in Ext.dataview.DataView.onAfterRender) -- D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\touch\src\dataview
\DataView.js:892
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.Decorator.setDisabled) -- D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\touch\src\Decorator.js:157

[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.data.ArrayStore.loadData) -- D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\touch\src\data\ArrayStore.js:64
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.fx.animation.Wipe.getData) -- D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\touch\src\fx\animation\Wipe.js:119:7
[INF] merging 0 input resources into D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\cordova\www\resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\cordova\www\resources
[INF] merging 87 input resources into D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\cordova\www
[INF] merged 0 resources into D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\cordova\www
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
identical ../css/app.css
[INF] Copying page resources to D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\cordova\www
[INF] Writing content to D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA/cordova/www/microloader.js
[INF] Appending content to D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA/cordova/www/microloader.js
[INF] Building output markup to D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA/cordova/www/index.html
[INF] Writing content to D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA/cordova/www/index.html
[INF] [Cordova] Attempting Cordova Build for platforms "android"
[INF] [shellscript]
[INF] [shellscript] D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\cordova>cordova  build android
[INF] [shellscript] Running command: D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\cordova\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat
[INF] [shellscript] events.js:85
[INF] [shellscript]       throw er; // Unhandled '''error''' event
[INF] [shellscript]             ^
[INF] [shellscript] Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
[INF] [shellscript]     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
[INF] [shellscript]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1046:32)
[INF] [shellscript]     at child_process.js:1137:20
[INF] [shellscript]     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
[INF] [shellscript] ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: D:\Sviluppo\varie\source\PROGETTI\GeoMapTematicPA\GeoMapTematicPA\cordova\platfrms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
[INF] [shellscript] You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

Thanks in advance, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why my question has been downvoted.

Comment: Have you ensured that your path is correctly set in relation to the Android SDK?

Comment: I answered my own question, you can see the solution here below. The problem was about the path as you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested here,
[Cordova / Ionic build error (sometimes): don't have required environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458284/cordova-ionic-build-error-sometimes-dont-have-required-environment), what to do is Copy and paste this "%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\" to the enviroment variables Path.