# Cordova Error "You may not have the required environment..."

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build my first app for android with the help of cordova. When I put `cordova build` into the console, I get the error:

```
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1...
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458284/cordova-ionic-build-error-sometimes-dont-have-required-environment) says that it is necessary to put this in the path:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

But it still doesn't work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXEio.png

Comment: did you install the Android SDK and include it in your path?

Comment: Yes. I read a lot of articles. All that can be added to PATH.

Comment: ;%ANT_BIN%;%ANDROID_HOME%;%ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS%;%ANDROID_TOOLS%;%ANT%;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%NPM%