# ionic build android error on windows

Tags: ionic-framework

Good day, i am getting an error whenever i build my ionic project, what could i have done wrong ? i have good internet connection and and my environment path is right base from the tutorials i saw online, and i also have tried what others did (who posted here at stack) but still it didn't work since i believe we have different problem.

links i tried: [Cordova Error "You may not have the required environment..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30946925/cordova-error-you-may-not-have-the-required-environment)

[image]

Comment: Have you installed `node.js`, `Ant`, `JDK`, `JRE` and `Android SDK` in that order? Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153915/ionic-build-android-error) for more information.

Comment: Yes, all of them, @Guillem Vicens, i just dont know how to read the error so that i will know what is missing or problem

Comment: Try using the `verbose` flag `-d`  when doing your build. I think it was something like `ionic -d build`

Comment: it recognizes the -d as not valid task. my eyes hurts seeing this red lines of error. Tsk, dont even know where or how did i get it

Comment: Try `cordova -d build android`

Comment: still the same, @GuillemVicens, why what was the error? i saw that it stop at gradle something..

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. AFAIK a `Gradle` error when building usually means some misconfiguration happened, be it paths, missing libraries or others. If you can, I would advise to reinstall everything and check every step. Sorry I can not be of more help.

Comment: I have solved my problem through "cordova build android -- --ant" saw it on the internet. Its a way on building app using ant instead of gradle. Because the problem with mine was on gradle. Thanks though