# if i update cordova to a newer version is it necessary to update ionic and all other plugins? how does the changes effect?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have updated cordova and all other plugins. When I tried generating apk, its showing

> "doesnot have required environment or OS to install"

I am not able figure out where the problem is.

this is version info of my app..

```
Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.7
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.3
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v0.12.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried removing Android platform?

```
ionic platform remove android
```

and then add it again:

```
ionic platform add android
```

or maybe this can be useful:
[Cordova / Ionic build error (sometimes): don't have required environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458284/cordova-ionic-build-error-sometimes-dont-have-required-environment)

Comment: Thankieuu so much.! But still aint able to get the output.! There are so many errors in my adb logcat